# {% extends "view/base.html" %}

Tags: python, templates, djangoappengine

`{% extends "base.html" %}` works fine, but I want to point to a
static_dir.

Here is app.yaml:

```
- url: /view
 static_dir: static/view
```

Here is `main.py`:

```
template_values = {
       'url': url,
       'url_linktext': url_linktext,
       }
       path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
       self.response.out.write(template.render(path,
template_values))
```

Here is the error:

> *raise TemplateSyntaxError, "Template
>   %r cannot be extended, because it
>   doesn't exist" % parent
>   TemplateSyntaxError: Template
>   'view/base.html' cannot be extended,
>   because it doesn't exist*

You can browse to the base.html, but class main() cannot see it.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Files served as static assets are just that, and not templates. If you want to extend a template, it has to be in a template directory.